# Invoking Deep Link from Cortana with authentication

Tags: botframework, cortana-skills-kit

I'm trying to get my Cortana Skill (from a Web based Bot) to play a specific album on Groove.

Playing the album can be achieved with a Deep Link like [this one](https://music.microsoft.com/Album/bcafef07-0100-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?action=play), although if you try it you will probably just launch the Windows Store.

That happens because that link requires you to be authenticated in the `music.microsoft.com` endpoint. But invoking the Deep Link from Cortana's `LaunchUri` laves no room for setting an Authorization header, so there's really no way to guarantee that the user will be have previously authentified.

Is it possible to make this work seamlessly by persisting the auth token and passing it through Cortana somehow?

Comment: How exactly are you running a Cortana skill "from a Web Based Bot"?

Comment: That's basically the only way. Cortana will forward the message to the bot and its response to the user, acting as a channel. Similarly to Hero Cards, if the bot answers with a predefined JSON defining LaunchUri she will launch it.